# How to prevent losing nanoseconds in numpy astype

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When I case `object` to `datetime64[ns]` then nanoseconds are lost. Why is it happening and how can this be fixed?
In python 3.6 and 3.7 same behaviour.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.ndarray(1, dtype=object)
a[0] = pd.Timestamp.max
print(a)
print(a.astype('datetime64[ns]'))
```

In the output we can see that nanoseconds are zeroed out

```
[Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')]
['2262-04-11T23:47:16.854775000']
```

The original problem came out from pandas dataframe and this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col'])
#df.loc[0] = [None]     # uncommenting this line makes nanoseconds being dropped
df.loc[0] = [pd.Timestamp.max]
print(df['col'].values.astype('datetime64[ns]'))
```

*Update*
Numpy docs says that nanoseconds are supported only for datetime values within `[ 1678 AD, 2262 AD]`.
But the issue is reproduced for datetime values inside the range:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.ndarray(1, dtype=object)
a[0] = pd.Timestamp(2020, 7, 31, 12, 12, 12, 123456, 789)
print(a)
print(a.astype('datetime64[ns]'))
```

In the output we can see that nanoseconds are zeroed out

```
[Timestamp('2020-07-31 12:12:12.123456789')]
['2020-07-31T12:12:12.123456000']
```

Comment: `a.astype('datetime64[ns]')` drops nanoseconds, as you showed above.  But `pd.to_datetime(a)` keeps nanoseconds.

Comment: I cannot use `pd.to_datetime(a)` because it does not support dates greater than 2062 year. Should I write code as `try: pd.to_datetime(a)   except: astype('datetime64[ns]')` ?

Comment: Nanosecond resolution has the date range [ 1678 AD, 2262 AD].  Microsecond resolution has the range [290301 BC, 294241 AD].  Please see the 'Datetime Units' section of the NumPy docs for more details:  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html

Comment: > Nanosecond resolution has the date range [ 1678 AD, 2262 AD]
Thank you. this helped a lot to understand how things work.
But even for dates inside nanosecond resolution range -> `astype` looses nanos :(

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally found workaround.
`fillna` restores nanoseconds!

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col'])
df.loc[0] = [None]
df.loc[0] = [pd.Timestamp(2020, 7, 31, 12, 12, 12, 123456, 789)]
print(df['col'].values.astype('datetime64[ns]'))
df['col'] = df['col'].fillna('')
print(df['col'].values.astype('datetime64[ns]'))
```

Output:

```
['2020-07-31T12:12:12.123456000'] 
['2020-07-31T12:12:12.123456789']
```

Comment: That's ridiculous!  I suggest filing an issue here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues